# Does a process that is not a shell process have shell variables?

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables

A shell (for example: the bash shell) have the concept of shell variables and the concept of environment variables.

But what about other processes that are not shell processes (for example: Firefox, gedit, etc.), do these processes also have shell variables or do they only have environment variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-shell process does not have shell variables. A C program has C variables, an `awk` program has `awk` variables, a Perl program has Perl variables, etc., and these are all in their own ways very much different from shell variables.

The reason another process do not have shell variables (or gets to access shell variables) is that shell variables are not exported (i.e. they are not environment variables), and also because some shells allows for attaching more information to a shell variable than just a string value, such as attributes for read-only variables, integer-only variables, etc. These type attributes (see the `typeset` built-in command) can't be applied to an environment variable *and be used* in another process.

Some shells (like `bash`) also supports arrays and associative arrays. These structures are too complex for the simple key-value pair format, where both the key (the variable name) and the value are plain text strings, imposed on environment variables, which means that these can't be exported for use in a generic other process.

All processes have access to the environment variables inherited from their parent processes. Depending on language, there are different ways for a program to access these.

A C program may use `getenv()`, an `awk` program may use its associative array `ENVIRON`, and a Perl program may use its `%ENV` hash to access environment variables, for example.

I don't know `gedit`, but in `vim`, you may access environment variables with a shell-like syntax:

```
:echo $HOME
```

for example.  The `echo` here has nothing to do with `echo` in the shell, it just happens to work in a similar way. Also, the `$HOME` string just happens to be the way that `vim` exposes environment variables to the user.